# Removing sensitive data from an AWS CodeCommit Git repo with git-filter-repo

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, git-filter-repo

I discovered a script that had a password in it and was committed many years ago to source control in AWS CodeCommit.  Since then, a completely new script has been created that does the same job without a password, so all I needed to do to "clean up" was make it look like the file had never existed, while preserving the rest of my team's repo history.

[GitHub wrote official "Removing sensitive data from a repository" documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#using-git-filter-repo) that clarifies what data you can't self-service remove from GitHub, but I can't find any such documentation from AWS CodeCommit.

I decided to try using GitHub's instructions against CodeCommit anyway, and see how it went.  It didn't go too well.

1. I completely removed `c:\my_repo\` from my hard drive and re-cloned it from the cloud *(replacing `c:\my_repo\.git\config` from a backup)*.
2. From `MINGW64:/c/my_repo`, I ran `git filter-repo --invert-paths --path sub_folder/bad_script.java`.
3. In Windows File Explorer, I saw that there was no longer a `c:\my_repo\sub_folder\bad_script.java` file.
4. In SourceTree, in the commit where `sub_folder/bad_script.java` had been added to the repo *(call it `1234567890987654321`)*, I saw that it was no longer in the list of files added.  Neat!
5. In AWS CodeCommit's web console, I took notes on a before-state -- the file existed and had a password in its body at:

   - `https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codecommit/repositories/my_repo/browse/refs/heads/main/--/sub_folder/bad_script.java?#`
   - `https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codecommit/repositories/my_repo/commit/1234567890987654321?region=my-region`
   - `https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codecommit/repositories/my_repo/browse/1234567890987654321/--/sub_folder?region=my-region`
   - `https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codecommit/repositories/my_repo/browse/0987654321234567890/--/sub_folder?region=my-region` *(commit `987654321234567890` being a later one that didn't edit the file, but I found it this way by browsing the file tree of that commit)*.
6. The one thing I skipped from GitHub's instructions was committing a `.gitignore` file before pushing, but I didn't think it'd be relevant since git-filter-repo had deleted the file off my hard drive.
7. After fixing `c:\my_repo\.git\config` to point to AWS again after git-filter-repo had removed the pointer, from `MINGW64:/c/my_repo`, I ran `git push origin --force --all`.
8. In AWS CodeCommit's web console, `https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codecommit/repositories/my_repo/browse/refs/heads/main/--/sub_folder/bad_script.java?#` was gone.  I got a `PathDoesNotExistException` header with a `Could not find path sub_folder/bad_script.java;` body as a big red error message.
9. However, in AWSCodeCommit's web console, the file still existed and had a password in its body at the remaining three URLs:

   - `https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codecommit/repositories/my_repo/commit/1234567890987654321?region=my-region`
   - `https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codecommit/repositories/my_repo/browse/1234567890987654321/--/sub_folder?region=my-region`
   - `https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codecommit/repositories/my_repo/browse/0987654321234567890/--/sub_folder?region=my-region`
10. I completely removed `c:\my_repo\` from my hard drive again and re-cloned it from the cloud *(replacing `c:\my_repo\.git\config` from a backup)* again, and the files still don't show up in SourceTree's view of the history, so I ... think this might just be an AWS problem?

Has anyone successfully deleted a file from CodeCommit history?  Are there steps I need to work with AWS staff to accomplish, like GitHub mentioned in their docs for their service?  Is there something better I can do with my approach to cleaning `bad_script.java` off my local copy of the repo -- maybe some fatal flaw in the steps I took?